# Winged special ability in RM&M

Tags: mazes-and-minotaurs

How does the Winged special ability effect melee combat in [Revised Mazes & Minotaurs](http://mazesandminotaurs.free.fr/revised.html)? Where is it mentioned in the rules?

Comment: @Jadasc: Thanks for creating the tag, I don't have the rep here yet.

Comment: No worries — happy to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maze Master's Guide, page 21.

> **Winged**
>
> The creature can fly. When using full movement, a
> flying creature’s movement rate is quadrupled, it
> cannot be hit by Melee attacks and all Missile
> attacks against it are made with a penalty of -2. This
> ability also adds +2 to the creature’s Evasion.

It earns 5 extra glory. (See MMG page 24)

Comment: Can it still be hit when it isn't using full movement?

Comment: The rules don't specify. I'd say, yes. Best Bet? Ask Ollie LeGrand yourself. He does answer rules questions.

Comment: Remember: Old School Gaming requires application of large doses of common sense in place of detailed lists of rule and exceptions.